# Grammar and meaning of: Give back to someone for something

Tags: meaning-in-context

I'm writing a letter and I came up with the following sentence:

> I want to give back to the community for what it has been giving me my whole life.

I'm struggling with its meaning and grammatical correctness.

1. When I researched the first part of the sentence with "give back to", I only found examples that end the sentence with "give back to community." but never continue with "for what...". Does such combination even make sense in English? And if it does, is it perceived in a positive way or in a negative way? For example, is it perceived as if I'm thankful for what they've been giving me or it's rather perceived in a way that I want to punish them?
2. Is it correct to say "the community ... for what it has been" or it's better to say "the community ... for what they have been"?
3. Is it correct to say "for what it has been giving me my whole life" or it's better to say "for what it has been giving me **through**/**throughout** my whole life"

Comment: (1) "I want to give **something** back to the community **in return** for... (2) Yes, it's correct - _community_ is singular. (3) _My whole life_ or _all my life_ are OK.

Comment: Thank you very much @KateBunting for the answer. Is it possible not to include "something" in "give something back", would such sentence make sense? The thing is that in the previous sentences in the letter I pretty much give an idea of what I want to give back and if I add "something" here, it sounds to me that it could add confusion.

Comment: In my opinion, _give something back_ is much more idiomatic and does not conflict with the fact that you have already specified what that 'something' is.

Comment: Thank you @KateBunting. Lastly, do you know if this sentence could be in any way perceived negatively?

Comment: The negative sense would be _pay them back for what they did to me_.